# Dropdown Menu Element Not Displaying

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, display

I'm making a website that uses a group of images as a menu.

I was able to get one side to properly display the dropdown (slideout, in this case) menus. But even though both sides are identical, the other one does not display the menu on mouseOver.

I looked through the code for the last hour, and just can't find what is wrong.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wd8rt0Lz/5/).

Thanks :)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: aliceblue
}

.topbar{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color:#605E5E;
    border-bottom-style:inset;
    border-bottom-color: #888888;
}

.touch-menu{
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#eda954+0,e5933b+29,e59f54+56,e89230+79,e89230+91,e89230+100 */
    background: rgb(237,169,84); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(237,169,84,1) 0%, rgba(229,147,59,1) 29%, rgba(229,159,84,1) 56%, rgba(232,146,48,1) 79%, rgba(232,146,48,1) 91%, rgba(232,146,48,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(237,169,84,1) 0%,rgba(229,147,59,1) 29%,rgba(229,159,84,1) 56%,rgba(232,146,48,1) 79%,rgba(232,146,48,1) 91%,rgba(232,146,48,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(237,169,84,1) 0%,rgba(229,147,59,1) 29%,rgba(229,159,84,1) 56%,rgba(232,146,48,1) 79%,rgba(232,146,48,1) 91%,rgba(232,146,48,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eda954', endColorstr='#e89230',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.slideout-content-top-left, .slideout-content-bottom-left {
    display: none;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    min-width: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: #736E6F;
    z-index: 1;
}

.slideout-content-top-right, .slideout-content-bottom-right {
    display: none;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #736E6F;
    min-width: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.menu-top-right :hover + .slideout-content-top-right , .menu-bottom-right :hover + .slideout-content-bottom-right  {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slideout-content-bottom-right:hover , .slideout-content-top-right:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-top-left :hover + .slideout-content-top-left , .menu-bottom-left :hover + .slideout-content-bottom-left {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slideout-content-bottom-left:hover , .slideout-content-bottom-left:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}


.touch-menu img:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.25);
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu-top-left , .menu-bottom-left , .menu-bottom-right, .menu-top-right {
    flex: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}


.menu-bottom-left img, .menu-top-left img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 95%;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.menu-bottom-right img , .menu-top-right img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 95%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Heter Iska</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <style>
    body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topbar" align="center">
            <h1>Links of Links</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class="touch-menu" align="center">
        
        <div class="column slideout-left" align="right">
            <div class="menu-top-left" >
                <div class="slideout-content-top-left" id="top-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">scaleLink 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">scaleLink 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">scaleLink 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <img class="slideout" src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
            </div>
        
            <div class="menu-bottom-left" >
                <div class="slideout-content-bottom-left" id="bottom-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">bookLink 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">bookLink 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">bookLink 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <img class="slideout " src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="Book" >
            </div>
            
        </div>  
    
        <div class="column slideout-right" align="left">
            <div class= "menu-top-right">
                <img class="slideout " src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="topGavel">
                <div class="slideout-content-top-right" id="top-right" >
                    <ul class="slidelist">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ugavelLink 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ugavelLink 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ugavelLink 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="menu-bottom-right">
                <img class="slideout" src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="bottomGavel">
                <div class="slideout-content-bottom-right" id="bottom-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">lgavelLink 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">lgavelLink 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">lgavelLink 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>          
            
        </div>
        


<!-- Footer  -->
<footer class="w3-container w3-padding-2 w3-center w3-opacity w3-dark-grey w3-xlarge">
  <p class="w3-medium">Powered by <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=emb_logo" target="_blank">Barack Obama</a></p>
</footer>

<script>
function expandTab(n) {
    document.getElemen
    }
</script>   
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is wrong. You are using `+` instead `>`

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: aliceblue
}

.topbar {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #605E5E;
    border-bottom-style: inset;
    border-bottom-color: #888888;
}

.touch-menu {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#eda954+0,e5933b+29,e59f54+56,e89230+79,e89230+91,e89230+100 */
    background: rgb(237, 169, 84); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(237, 169, 84, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 147, 59, 1) 29%, rgba(229, 159, 84, 1) 56%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 79%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 91%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(237, 169, 84, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 147, 59, 1) 29%, rgba(229, 159, 84, 1) 56%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 79%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 91%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(237, 169, 84, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 147, 59, 1) 29%, rgba(229, 159, 84, 1) 56%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 79%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 91%, rgba(232, 146, 48, 1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eda954', endColorstr='#e89230', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.slideout-content-top-left, .slideout-content-bottom-left {
    display: none;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    min-width: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #736E6F;
    z-index: 1;
}

.slideout-content-top-right, .slideout-content-bottom-right {
    display: none;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #736E6F;
    min-width: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.menu-top-right:hover > .slideout-content-top-right, .menu-bottom-right:hover > .slideout-content-bottom-right {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slideout-content-bottom-right:hover, .slideout-content-top-right:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-top-left:hover > .slideout-content-top-left, .menu-bottom-left:hover > .slideout-content-bottom-left {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slideout-content-bottom-left:hover, .slideout-content-bottom-left:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}


.touch-menu img:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.25);
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu-top-left, .menu-bottom-left, .menu-bottom-right, .menu-top-right {
    flex: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}


.menu-bottom-left img, .menu-top-left img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 95%;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.menu-bottom-right img, .menu-top-right img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 95%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: It works somewhat now. When I had it as +, it only dropped down when my cursor was over the image. Now it pops open if the mouse is just within that div (which is a quarter of the screen). How can I get it to only pop up if I hover over the image?

Comment: @Exosylver check this one https://jsfiddle.net/091ehua3/